# Change password encryption in GET users/login request with loopback

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs

I have to implement a strongloop API connected to an existing MySQL Database. I'm currently trying to create a model based on User, but I am kinda struggling with the loggin in request.

The problem is: the users in my DB already have a password, but the encryption isn't the same as the one used in loopback. Is there a way to change all password-linked requests in strongloop in order to use my encryption? And a little trickier: is there a way to chose the encryption based on a boolean value in my model (ie. I'm thinking about migrating all the passwords, but I have to make sure my users can still log in with their old and dirty encrypted password)

Thank you,

bjorge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could, but it would be pretty painful to alter the built-ins to that degree. It would probably be better to inject new routes in a boot script, and conditionally use the helper functions on the built-in `User` model, e.g. `User.verify()`, `User.confirm()`, etc.

Something like this roughly:

```
module.exports = function (app) {
    //get User model from the express app
    var UserModel = app.models.User;

    //get your custom model
    var customModel = app.models.someCustomModel;

    app.post('/login', function (req, res) {        

        //parse user credentials from request body
        const userCredentials = {
            "username": req.body.username,
            "password": req.body.password
        }

        if (customModel.someBoolean == true) {
            //do your login stuff
        } else {
            UserModel.login(userCredentials, 'user', function (err, result) {           
                //handle response
            });     
        }

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is based on the answer from @amuramoto but with two additional assumptions

1. That you will need the accessToken after your custom Login
2. That you store a boolean in your database if its still using the old password or not

Here is the code:

```
module.exports = function(app) {
    //get User model from the express app
    var UserModel = app.models.User;
    app.post('/login', function(req, res) {

        //parse user credentials from request body
        const userCredentials = {
            "username": req.body.username,
            "password": req.body.password
        }

        UserModel.findOne({
            "where": {
                "username": userCredentials.username
            }
        }, function(err, user) {


            if (user.isOldPassword == true) {
                //do your login method


                // Create the Access Token as a return Value
                user.createAccessToken(5000, function(err, token) {
                    res.json({
                        "token": result.id,
                        "ttl": result.ttl
                    });
                })


            } else {
                UserModel.login(userCredentials, 'user', function(err, result) {
                    //handle response

                    if (err) {
                        res.status(401).json({
                            "error": "login failed"
                        });
                        return;
                    }

                    //transform response to only return the token and ttl
                    res.json({
                        "token": result.id,
                        "ttl": result.ttl
                    });
                });
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar situation. We wanted to use our own user model and password schema and ultimately decided to not use the Loopback authentication (or user model) at all. As [amuramoto](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4446515/amuramoto) mentioned above this was indeed a bit painful. But we were able to accomplish it by using our own [JWT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON_Web_Token) implementation along with our own user login model.  Here's the general idea...

```
// *************
// Login Model
// *************

let Jwt = require('jwt-simple');

// Custom login/authentication goes here...
export function getToken(data, callback) {

    if (!data || !data.companyid || !data.userid || !data.password)
        return callback(null, Lib.returnEvent(false, 'Unauthorized', 401))

    try {

            Login.verifyLogin(data.companyid, data.userid, data.password).always(function (verified, payload) {

                if (verified) {

                    let token = Jwt.encode(payload, 'JWTPASSWORD');

                    let eventInfo: Type.Event = {
                        success: true,
                        messagenbr: 200,
                        returnvalue: token
                    }

                    return callback(null, eventInfo);

                } else {
                    return callback(null, Lib.returnEvent(false, 'Unauthorized', 401))
                }

            })

    } catch(e) {
        return callback(null, Lib.returnEvent(false, 'Unauthorized', 401))
    }
}

export function remoteMethod(model: any) {

    model.remoteMethod(
        'getToken',
        {
            http: { verb: 'post' },
            accepts: {arg: 'data', type: 'data' },
            returns: [
                { arg: 'eventinfo', type: 'data', root: true },
            ],
        }
    )
    return model;
}
```

Then, use [Loopback's middleware 'parse' phase](https://docs.strongloop.com/display/public/LB/Defining+middleware) for token validation.

```
// ***************************
// Authenication - Parse Request (set filters)
// ***************************
app.middleware('parse', parseRequest)

  function parseRequest(req, res, next) {

    try {

        //
        let token: Type.JwtToken = Login.getToken(req);

        // If this is the actual login then return. 
        // Otherwise it will block the login url.
        if (token && token.crowid && req.url != '/api/login/gettoken' ) {
            companyrowid = token.crowid;
        }

    } catch (e) {
        debug.log('parse', 'error.catch', e)
    }

    return next();
} 

........     

// ***************************
// Verify Authentication Token
// ***************************
app.middleware('auth:before', Login.authenticateToken)
```

Comment: I sure can see that was a painful development. That must work, but it's a bit complicated for me. Thank you anyway!